# Using iPhone camera to scan and OCR printed hand filled forms

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

Running competitions where contestants fill out forms with their results.

The results would look something like this:
[image]

What I want is to have a stack of these sheets in front of me and flip through them showing them to my phone and have it do the hard work of reading the data and telling me who made it through to the next round.

Tesseract and SwiftOCR could read the standard fonts but I can't find anyone using either to do handwriting.

Comment: why not enter that data directly into a computer? this is 2017. asking for library recommendations is off-topic.  websearch will yield any useful libraries out there

Comment: Entering data manually is the current setup. This is a project for fun.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Tesseract for handwriting recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556443/using-tesseract-for-handwriting-recognition)