# Handwriting OCR solution for a mobile app

Tags: mobile, ocr

I know that this question has been asked various times, but after 2 hours of searching and testing, I found only dated solutions that don't fit my specific problem.

**My Problem:**

I need to scan a document with a mobile camera, focus on one handwritten word, and get the text.

From that:
[image]
To: "FAFA"

**Requisite**

- Can be both a paid third part API solution or a mobile library (Java, Objective-C, or Javascript).
- Must work for both Android and iOS
- Accepted error rate: 0-10%

**Discarded solutions**

- Tesseract seems to not work well with handwriting text. Some solutions suggest manually train Tesseract, but the process seems hyper complicated. [Using Tesseract for handwriting recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556443/using-tesseract-for-handwriting-recognition)

Comment: 0% with ocr is a myth

Comment: @depperm I am not looking for a perfect solution: from 0 to 10%