# I am trying to extract the amount in words from cheque. I have already selected the Region of interest but not able to extract data from it correctly

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, handwriting-recognition

[Cheque Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0uKQ.jpg) I want to extract date, amount in figures, amount in words, account number, cheque number.
I have extracted date, account number and cheque number but unable to extract amount in words from the image.
[Here is the region of interest for the above. its size is (100x1210) px.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU6wi.jpg)
Image contains the amount of cheque in words.
Can you help in extracting the amount in words using OpenCV python?

Comment: this image seems like an output of a process. It could be better to share the source image so we may re-consider the problem. It would be better to edit your question too. Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do I get you right that you are asking how to do OCR on handwriting? Is this is a duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39576476/18667225 ?

Comment: Tesseract is not working, I have already tried it. I want a method to create a box around every individual word or whole text written so that I can extract data using my own ML model.

Comment: you handwrited text uses blue color. Maybe first you should use `cv.Range()` to select only blue pixels.